# JQuery we cant get the values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We can not get the values of this input fields with JQuery we only get the taskname's value the others are undefined. We can not get the values. We are using MVC.

```
<script>
    var name;
    var intro;
    var sdate;
    var edate;
    var layer;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on("click", function () {
            name = $("#validate-text").val();
            intro = $("#intro").get().val();
            layer = $("#layer option:checked").val();
            sdate = $("#sdate").val();
            edate = $("#edate").val();

        });
    });
    console.log(name, intro, layer, sdate, edate);
</script>
```

Comment: You need to move the `console.log` line in the function of the click listener. Now it just logs unset variables on load.

Comment: Share the relevant HTML code too. And you need to move `console.log` inside the `function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<script>
    var name;
    var intro;
    var sdate;
    var edate;
    var layer;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").on("click", function () {
            name = $("#validate-text").val();
            intro = $("#intro").get().val();
            layer = $("#layer option:checked").val();
            sdate = $("#sdate").val();
            edate = $("#edate").val();
            console.log(name + ", "+ intro + ", "+ layer + ", "+ sdate + ", "+ edate);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the correct solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve quality of your post. Remember that you're answering for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons behind your code suggestion.